# add connector plugin kafka by ambari

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, ambari, confluent-platform

im new in apache environment and it have something that makes me really wonder. My kafka was installed via ambari. so everything can be started by ambari's GUI. When kafka installed via ambari it includes kafka-connect. But what if i the connector i need is not included .
here are some the connectors that included.

```
/etc/kafka-connect-activemq
/etc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch
/etc/kafka-connect-ibmmq
/etc/kafka-connect-jdbc
/etc/kafka-connect-jms
/etc/kafka-connect-replicator
/etc/kafka-connect-s3
/etc/kafka-connect-storage-common
/etc/kafka-connect-activemq/ActiveMQSourceConnector.properties
/etc/kafka-connect-activemq/connect-avro-localhost.properties
/etc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/quickstart-elasticsearch.properties
/etc/kafka-connect-ibmmq/IbmMQSourceConnector.properties
/etc/kafka-connect-ibmmq/connect-avro-localhost.properties
/etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-quickstart-sqlite.properties
/etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-quickstart-sqlite.properties
/etc/kafka-connect-jms/ActiveMQSourceConnector.properties
/etc/kafka-connect-jms/JMSSourceConnector.properties
/etc/kafka-connect-jms/connect-avro-localhost.properties
/etc/kafka-connect-replicator/quickstart-replicator-unicluster.properties
/etc/kafka-connect-replicator/quickstart-replicator.properties
/etc/kafka-connect-replicator/replicator-connect-distributed.properties
/etc/kafka-connect-replicator/replicator-connect-standalone.properties
/etc/kafka-connect-replicator/replicator-log4j.properties
/etc/kafka-connect-replicator/replicator.properties
/etc/kafka-connect-s3/quickstart-s3.properties
/etc/kafka-connect-s3/quickstart-schema-source-for-s3.properties
```

but what i need is hdfs3-sink. How do i achieve it without confluent?

any suggestion will be appreciated so much. Thank you

Comment: Which HDFS 3 sink do you want to use?

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your respond, im a big fan of yours i watch some of your videos. Alright actualy i dont know much about kafka, but since i need to send my topic to hdfs3 i think i need  hdfs3 sink connector :kafka-connect-hdfs3. How many HDFS 3 sink out there? Thank you so much for your respond, really appreciate that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only HDFS 3 connector for Kafka Connect that I'm aware of is this one from Confluent: https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs3/.

To install it you can download the JAR directly, or use `confluent-hub` CLI tool to install it.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your responses, can you explain it more details? I ever install it by confluent hub. Everything run well in ambari. But when i do `confluent local status` everything is down. Can you explain it more for me. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, i've tried to install it. And i occurs another problem. Would you mind to check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62526864/kafka-to-hdfs-sink-missing-required-configuration-confluent-topic-bootstrap-ser   . thank you in advance